# The time evolution of the spin

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, quantum-spin, time-evolution

Suppose there is an electron described by the following spinor
$$
[\alpha(x,t),\beta(x,t)]
$$
with the two spin components along an axis. If we put this into the Schrödinger equation and the Hamiltonian does not depend on the spin, we get two independent equations for $\alpha(x,t)$ and $\beta(x,t)$. Normalization refers only to the whole Hilbert space
$$
\langle \alpha \vert \alpha \rangle + \langle \beta \vert \beta \rangle = 1
$$

Since the Schrödinger equation preserves norm, $\langle \alpha \vert \alpha \rangle$ and $\langle \beta \vert \beta \rangle$ are constant.

However, it may happen that the ratio $|\alpha(x,t)|/|\beta(x,t)|$ is not the same at different $x$ coordinates. Hence, the spin value is space dependent. How could you interpret this?

As an example, let's consider the Harmonic oscillator. Let the spinor be
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\left( \begin{array}{c} \phi_0(x) e^{-i\omega_0 t} \\  \phi_1(x) e^{-i\omega_1 t}\end{array} \right),
$$
where the subscripts $0,1$ stand for the ground state and the first excited state, respectively. The upper and lower parts of the spinor are solutions of the time-dependent Schrödinger equation. Now, the ratio $|\phi_0(x)|/|\phi_1(x)|$ is the function of space. Hence, the measurement of the spin would depend on the placement of the detector along axis x. Does it mean that the spin is a local quantity? Hence, there is no point to talk about global spin states although the spin operator commutes with the Hamiltonian for the harmonic oscillator.

Comment: I'm not understanding the source of the confusion. "The spin value is space dependent" seems easy enough to understand. Is this a homework problem?

Comment: This is not a homework problem, but textbooks almost never talk about this. I am uncertain about the situation. Many textbooks say that both components have the same space dependence.

Comment: To the extent the Hamiltonian involves gradients, it does affect the two components differently, so the spin evolves in time. What type of interpretation are you after? ***Have you tried a simple example*** ? Write it down here.

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: For a spin-$1/2$ particle in 1D the relevant Hilbert space is $H\cong L^2(\mathbb R)\otimes \mathbb C^2$. The probability to measure e.g. spin-up in a normalized state $|\psi\rangle \in H$ is $\langle \psi|\, \mathbb I_{L^2}\otimes P_+\,|\psi\rangle$, where $P_+:=|+\rangle\langle +|$ with the usual notation. Does this help?

Comment: You concocted an unmotivated, gonzo 2-spinor out of solutions of the 1-d QHO. What does this spinor have to do with spin, as understood in mainstream QM?

Comment: What you have observed here is that it is possible to entangled a particles position with it's spin

Comment: @BySymmetry But it is wrong that the probability for a measurement outcome of spin depends on the position, which OP is asking about, I guess.

Comment: @JasonFunderberker Iagree that if all you do is measure spin it is not position dependent. I was trying to address the part of the OPs question about how they should understand a state of this form